# Running a simulation for all unique combinations of a range of parameters

Tags: beginner, matlab, octave

I have written a script which is supposed to call the function at the bottom for each unique combination of values in the parameter vectors. That function is a simulation which I intend to run over all the unique combinations of those parameters. The simulation is run on a cluster, and the `sim_ind` for each of these jobs is pulled from the environment.

Currently, my solution is to build a matrix with each row corresponding to a unique set of parameters. Then the `sim_ind` value (passed from the environment) is used to determine which unique set of parameters will be used in that iteration by indexing the matrix.

The following is the code that I am using, which works:

```matlab
% getting sim_ind from env
AI = getenv('PBS_ARRAYID');
sim_ind = str2num(AI);

time_slots = 40000;

% parameter vectors
up_down_ratio_arr = [1];
traffic_load_arr = [ 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 100, Inf ];
blocked_modes_ind_arr = [1 2 3];
traffic_model_arr = [1 2];

% total number of unique combinations
uniq = length(up_down_ratio_arr) * length(traffic_load_arr) * length(blocked_modes_ind_arr) * length(traffic_model_arr);
parameters = zeros(uniq, 4);

% propagating the parameter list matrix
counter = 0;
for i = up_down_ratio_arr
    for j = traffic_load_arr
        for k = blocked_modes_ind_arr
            for l = traffic_model_arr
                counter = counter + 1;

                parameters(counter, 1) = i;
                parameters(counter, 2) = j;
                parameters(counter, 3) = k;
                parameters(counter, 4) = l;
            end
        end
    end
end

% wrapping the sim_ind
ind = mod(sim_ind, uniq);

% mod maps all multiples of the largest index to zero
if ind == 0
    ind = uniq;
end

% retrieving a parameter set
up_down_ratio = parameters(ind,1);
traffic_load = parameters(ind,2);
blocked_modes_ind = parameters(ind,3);
traffic_model = parameters(ind,4);

% call the routine
MainCode_Single_Backahul_Cell_Sch(time_slots, up_down_ratio, traffic_load, blocked_modes_ind, traffic_model, ceil(sim_ind/uniq) );
```

Is there a better way?

I have a version in which I use `mod` to map each value of the `sim_ind` parameter to a value that exists in the range of each vector. The problem with this solution was that not all the combination were unique. For example, in the following code `traffic_load_arr` is of size 10, and `traffic_model_arr` is of size 2. Therefore, whenever the 8th element of `traffic_load_arr` is selected; i.e. `mod(sim_ind, 10) == 8`, then the 2nd element of `traffic_model_arr` must also be selected. As a results, the parameter combination of `traffic_load == 10` and `traffic_model == 2` will never be formed.

I would appreciate for all code to be cross compatible with MATLAB and Octave.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a [full factorial experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_experiment), you may want to avoid constructing the whole matrix just to get the factor levels for a single experiment, especially if you have a large number of factors and levels and you are using a language where loops are not very efficient. Here is how you can do it using `mod`.

In a single factor experiment, you run the experiment over the range of values of the first factor. This is easy to do using `mod`: use `mod(sim_ind, nlevels_factor1)`, or

```
mod(sim_ind-1, nlevels_factor1) + 1
```

if you want to start at one (since MATLAB indexes arrays from 1).

To extend the experiment to a second factor, you want this new factor to have its first level value for the first `nlevels_factor1` runs, then its second level value for the second `nlevels_factor1` runs, etc... all the way up till the `nlevels_factor1*nlevels_factor2`th run.

You'll use `mod` again, but now you want the first argument to `mod` to be 1 for the first `nlevels_factor1` runs, 2 for the next `nlevels_factor1` runs, etc. So instead of passing the `sim_index` (or `sim_index-1`) to mod, you'll pass `ceil(sim_index/nlevels_factor1)`, which has value 1 for the first `nlevels_factor1` runs, 2 for the next `nlevels_factor1` runs, etc. Your factor level for the second factor will be

```
mod(ceil(sim_index/nlevels_factor1) - 1, nlevels_factor2) + 1
```

if you want to start from 1.

You can continue this procedure to extend your experiment to any number of factors. Just make the divisor inside the `ceil` equal to the product of the number of levels of all of the previous factors.

Here's what it might look like for your example:

```matlab
% getting sim_ind from env
AI = getenv('PBS_ARRAYID');
sim_ind = str2num(AI);

time_slots = 40000;

% parameter vectors
up_down_ratio_arr = [1];
traffic_load_arr = [ 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 100, Inf ];
blocked_modes_ind_arr = [1 2 3];
traffic_model_arr = [1 2];

size_up_down_ratio = length(up_down_ratio_arr);
size_traffic_load  = length(traffic_load_arr);
size_blocked_modes = length(blocked_modes_ind_arr);
size_traffic_model = length(traffic_model_arr);

% total number of unique combinations
uniq = size_up_down_ratio*size_traffic_load*size_blocked_modes*size_traffic_model;

% repeat each value once: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4...
i_up_down_ratio = mod(sim_ind - 1,size_up_down_ratio) + 1;
% repeat each value size_so_far times:
% 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3...
size_so_far = size_up_down_ratio;
i_traffic_load  = mod(ceil(sim_ind/size_so_far) - 1, size_traffic_load) + 1;
size_so_far = size_so_far*size_traffic_load;
i_blocked_modes  = mod(ceil(sim_ind/size_so_far) - 1, size_blocked_modes) + 1;
size_so_far = size_so_far*size_blocked_modes;
i_traffic_model = mod(ceil(sim_ind/size_so_far) - 1, size_traffic_model) + 1;

up_down_ratio = up_down_ratio_arr(i_up_down_ratio);
traffic_load  = traffic_load_arr(i_traffic_load);
blocked_modes_ind = blocked_modes_ind_arr(i_blocked_modes);
traffic_model = traffic_model_arr(i_traffic_model);

% call the routine
MainCode_Single_Backahul_Cell_Sch(time_slots, up_down_ratio, traffic_load, blocked_modes_ind, traffic_model, ceil(sim_ind/uniq) );
```

Comment: Very nice! =) +1 from me!

Answer (score 7):

NOTE: The code in this answer is rather compact, in order to avoid a lot of scrolling. You might want to put in some additional spaces and line breaks.

You know how to do this! Your code looks very nice and clean!

But, this hurts my MATLAB eyes:

```
for i = up_down_ratio_arr
    for j = traffic_load_arr
        for k = blocked_modes_ind_arr
            for l = traffic_model_arr
                counter = counter + 1;

                parameters(counter, 1) = i;
                parameters(counter, 2) = j;
                parameters(counter, 3) = k;
                parameters(counter, 4) = l;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

It's the prime example of something that should be done without loops... One thing that was hurting even more was that I apparently couldn't make a vectorized approach that was faster. The reason why it appeared to be slow was because I tried timing it with `tic/toc`.

**Tips:** Don't use `tic/toc` when benchmarking, use the superior `timeit`! When benchmarking with `timeit` I got results that was much in favor of vectorization. (Phew)

The vectorized approach (creds to [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo)) in a function, so that I can time it:

```
function parameters = vectorized_approach(up_down_ratio_arr, traffic_load_arr, blocked_modes_ind_arr, traffic_model_arr)
vectors = {up_down_ratio_arr, traffic_load_arr, blocked_modes_ind_arr, traffic_model_arr};
n = numel(vectors); %// number of vectors
parameters = cell(1,n); %// pre-define to generate comma-separated list
[parameters{end:-1:1}] = ndgrid(vectors{end:-1:1}); %// the reverse order in these two
%// comma-separated lists is needed to produce the rows of the result matrix in
%// lexicographical order
parameters = cat(n+1, parameters{:}); %// concat the n n-dim arrays along dimension n+1
parameters = reshape(parameters,[],n);
end
```

Your loop approach is placed in the function `loop_approach` (I won't repeat it here).

```
up_down_ratio_arr = [1]; 
traffic_load_arr = [ 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 100, Inf ];
blocked_modes_ind_arr = [1 2 3];
traffic_model_arr = [1 2];

f = @() loop_approach(up_down_ratio_arr, traffic_load_arr, blocked_modes_ind_arr, traffic_model_arr);
g = @() vectorized_approach(up_down_ratio_arr, traffic_load_arr, blocked_modes_ind_arr, traffic_model_arr);
isequal(f(),g())    
ans =    
     1 

timeit(f)/timeit(g)
ans =
    1.6072
```

So, for your input variables, the vectorized approach is about 60% faster than the loops. Let's make the `up_down_ratio_arr` a bit longer:

```
up_down_ratio_arr = [1:5];
f = @() loop_approach(up_down_ratio_arr, traffic_load_arr, blocked_modes_ind_arr, traffic_model_arr);
g = @() vectorized_approach(up_down_ratio_arr, traffic_load_arr, blocked_modes_ind_arr, traffic_model_arr);
isequal(f(),g())
ans =
     1

timeit(f)/timeit(g)
ans =
    7.2192
```

So, the vectorized approach is quite a bit faster for the data you posted in the question, and a lot faster for larger data sets.

---

**Let's continue:**

In general, [`numel` is better than `length`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3119739/2338750), at least for long vectors. I recommend you get used to using it every time!

This, could be simplified:

```
if ind == 0
    ind = uniq;
end
```

This does the same job, and avoids the `if`: `ind(ind == 0) = uniq;`.

I don't think I would have done `ceil(sim_ind/uniq)` in the function call. I suggest you calculate this and give it a descriptive name (probably the same as in the function you're calling). Then use that variable as input argument.